# ASP MVC3 checkbox action without submit button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, button, controller, submit, checkbox

I am using ASP.net for a program with a number of check boxes and a submit button which initiates an action depending on the selected check boxes.

However, one of my check boxes should behave as this submit button, i.e, upon selecting/deselecting this check box, the same action as the button must be triggered. Can someone please help me in doing this (or perhaps direct me to a tutorial)

I have a controller class and model.

Thanks you

EDIT
The program look like:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("controllername", FormMethod.Get)) {
     @html.CheckBox("check1");
     @HTMl.Checkbos("check2");
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Everything else is pretty much handled in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript to listen to the check event of your check box and then invoke the form submit.

Assuming your markup of view is like this

```
<form id="yourFormId" action="user/post">
  <input type="checkbox" class="optionChk" value="1" /> One
  <input type="checkbox" class="optionChk" value="2" /> Two
  <input type="checkbox" class="optionChk" value="3" /> Three
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $(".optionChk").click(function(){
      var item=$(this);
      if(item.val()=="2")   //check your condition here
      {
         item.closest("form").submit();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**EDIT** : *As per the question edit.*

Change the CheckBox Helper method usage like the below to add a css class to the checkbox so that we can use that for the jQuery selection.

```
 @Html.CheckBox("check1",new { @class="optionChk"})
```

Comment: Thank you. Please see the edit. Since i am using a controller, how can i apply this in such a case?

Comment: your code should render the html like my sample. add a css class to your checkboxes for jQuery selection. you can either use the form ID (you have to mention that in your Html.Beginform method) or use closest function to get the form

Comment: error when adding the part new {class="optionChk"}. It says "Type or namespace definition, or end of file expected

Comment: Was a typo. Fixed it now. use the updated @Html.CheckBox method usage.

Answer (score 1):

imagining you have something like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()) {

  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chb_a" id="chb_a"> Option A
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chb_b" id="chb_b"> Option B
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chb_c" id="chb_c"> Option C
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chb_d" id="chb_d"> Option D
  </label>

  <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>

}
```

you can write a simple jQuery to complement:

```
$(".submit").click(function() {
  // find the <form> the element belongs and submit it
  $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

and with this, all you need is to add a class named `submit` to any checkbox or more buttons if you want them to submit

for example:

```
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chb_e" id="chb_e" class="submit"> Option E
  </label>
```

Comment: I am using @html.checkbox("chb_a") with no class. How can I have it reference the same class as that of the submit button? or is there an alternative way?

Comment: you just have to use an override to add the `htmlAtrributes`, in your case, like: `@Html.CheckBox("chb_a", new { @class = "submit" })`

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the click events on the checkboxes.

```
$( '.myCheckboxes' ).click(function () {
  var clickedBox = $( this );
  // now do something based on the clicked box...
});
```

If you need to know which checkboxes are checked, that's just another selector.

```
$( '.myCheckboxes:checked' ).each(function () {
  // Now you have access to each checked box.
  // Maybe you want to grab their values.
});
```

Just bind the checkbox to a click event. Assuming you have a way of uniquely identifying the checkbox that submits the form.

```
$( '#formSubmitCheckbox' ).click(function() {
  $( '#myForm' ).submit();
});
```